# Timestamp x hours ago and days after 24h

Tags: php, html, timestamp

I have this code which shows when a 'subject' was posted but it shows in days so for example if it was posted today then it will show 0 day(s) ago.. how can I make it to show if it was posted now to show for example 1 minute ago and to increase after 60 minutes in hours until 24 hours and after to change automatically in days like how it is now..
My code:

```
<h4><span class="label label-default">
  <?php
  $start = date_create($row['timestamp']);
  $end = date_create();
  $diff=date_diff($end,$start);  
  print_r($diff->days);
  ?>
 day(s) ago</span></h4>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for Carbon? http://carbon.nesbot.com. Example from their site: `echo Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans(); // '2 minutes ago'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function diffString($diff) {
    $units = ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"];
    $props = "ymdhis";
    foreach ($units as $i => $unit) {
        $prop = $props[$i];
        $num = $diff->$prop;
        if ($num) return "$num {$unit}" . ($num - 1 ? "s" : "");
    }
    return "0 seconds";
}
```

Example call:

```
$start = date_create('2016-07-28 16:23');
$end = date_create();
$diff=date_diff($end,$start);
echo diffString($diff) . " ago";
```

It will distinguish between singular and plural as well.

Comment: can you help me with this please? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655764/pagination-limit-per-page-pdo